# Making requests to external host on Docker container

Tags: vpn

I am trying to connect to a database that has an IP of x.x.x.x from my Docker container

Getting this error

```
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host (Host unreachable)
```

Tried running container using --network=host which has a similar approach to the above  attempt

Comment: What is the output of `docker network inspect bridge` command? Also See https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/#the-default-bridge-network for more details.

Comment: Can you reach that IP address without Docker?  (If it doesn’t work with host networking, I’d expect it to not work at all.). You’d need to configure your host’s routing tables to have a path to that address.

Comment: Can you provide your docker-compose file? Or provide details about how you start your docker containers. If you use the networking property, you should not have to use IP address of container, which could change one run to another anyway.

Comment: @David Maze yes it works outside of docker just fine so I'm not sure why it isn't in docker

Comment: Here is the thing, the ip 172.* is an internal ip for docker network, which is not accessible from out side. It's used by docker for its communication between containers. I would suggest you use a docker-compose to start up all application. I will post a sample docker compose file in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, here is the sample docker-compose file.

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  entitygraph:
    image: entitygraph-by-jar:latest
    container_name: entitygraph
    restart: always
    networks:
      - eg-net
    ports:
      - 9999:8080
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://eg-mysql/customers?useSSL=false
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: mysql

  eg-mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    networks:
      - eg-net
    container_name: eg-mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: customers
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:

networks:
  eg-net:
    name: eg-net
```

In this file, the application entitygraph is trying to talk to mysql. In my application, the connection string to mysql is as below,

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/customers?useSSL=false
```

So, docker will replace the `spring.datasource.url` property with the one I specified on my docker-compose file. Note that host:port is eg-mysql, which docker resolves to it's internal IP and will use it to communicate.

I don't know about your application architecture. If I know, I could give you more specific answer to your problem.